# The negative and positive predicates

Tags: emacs

I refer to [17.5.7.4 Predicates](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Predicates.html) and see the demonstration:

> — Function: zerop x
>
> ```
> Returns true if x is numerically zero, in any of the Calc data types. (Note that for some types, such as error forms and intervals,
> ```
>
> it never makes sense to return true.) In defmath, the expression ‘(= x
>   0)’ will automatically be converted to ‘(math-zerop x)’, and ‘(/= x
>   0)’ will be converted to ‘(not (math-zerop x))’.

However, it report error when apply it

```
ELISP> (math-zerop 0)
*** Eval error ***  Symbol’s function definition is void: math-zerop
ELISP> (math-zerop 1)
*** Eval error ***  Symbol’s function definition is void: math-zerop
```

What's the problem?

Comment: It seems `calc` is not loaded in your system. Run `(require 'calc)` and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs tries to lazy load (called autoloading) some of its features. `math-zerop` is defined as part of the `calc-misc` feature (in [calc-misc.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/calc/calc-misc.el)).

You can load it by `(require 'calc)` which loads the `calc-misc` feature.